# Published project not finding specified file when being opened

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am compiling a program to start my custom WoW server that I play by myself here at home.
The project built and compiled successfully but when I run the project every button gives the "cannot find specified file" error.

this is the error code:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at Server_CP_test.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
System.Private.CoreLib
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Server CP test
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 5.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 5.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Specialized
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Forms
    Assembly Version: 5.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core
    Assembly Version: 10.0.6.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.IO.FileSystem
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Common
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.2
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Threading
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Thread
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Memory
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Buffers
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.NonGeneric
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.Process
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Uri
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Metadata
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: n/a
    CodeBase: 
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
```

I am unable to add the code from the project as this question box just continually tells me that my question appears to have code that isnt formatted as code no matter how many times i keep retrying it using the code shortcut.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Const V As String = "Application.StartupPath + "
    Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
    testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("WoW Priv Server Control Panel.exe")
    Dim folderPath As String = testFile.DirectoryName
    Dim fileName As String = testFile.Name
    Dim fullPath As String
    fullPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(folderPath, fileName)
    Dim Database As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "1_Database.bat"
    Dim Auth As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "2_Login.exe"
    Dim World As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "3_world.exe"
    Dim StartAll As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "start_all_servers.bat"
    Dim StartAuthWorld As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "start_WORLD_AUTH_servers.bat"
    Dim CloseAll As String = "Application.StartupPath" & "\" & "batch close servers.bat"
End Class
```

Comment: `Application.StartupPath` should not be in quotes if you want it to be the startup path of the application. If it is in quotes, then it is the literal string "Application.StartupPath" and it won't be processed.

Comment: + one for what @AndrewMorton has said, would also replace all of that path string concatenation with IO.Path.Combine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0.  Not sure if any advantage  over FileSystem.CombinePath which you've already got there